# How to pipe tar.extractall from python

Tags: python, stdout, tar

I'm extracting a tarball using the tarfile module of python. I don't want the extracted files to be written on the disk, but rather get piped directly to another program, specifically bgzip. I'm also trying to use StringIO for that matter, but I get stuck even on that stage - the tarball gets extracted on the disk.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tarfile, StringIO
tar = tarfile.open("6genomes.tgz", "r:gz")
def enafun(members):
    for tarkati in tar:
        if tarkati.isreg():
            yield tarkati
reles = StringIO.StringIO()
reles.write(tar.extractall(members=enafun(tar)))
tar.close()
```

How then do I pipe correctly the output of tar.extractall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use **extractall** method, but you can use **getmembers** and **extractfile** methods instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tarfile, StringIO
reles = StringIO.StringIO()
with tarfile.open("6genomes.tgz", "r:gz") as tar:
    for m in tar.members():
        if m.isreg():
            reles.write(tar.extractfile(m).read())
# do what you want with "reles".
```

According to the documentation, extractfile() method can take a **TarInfo** and will return a **file-like object**. You can then get the content of that file with read().

[EDIT] I add what you asked me in comment as formatting in comment seems not to render properly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tarfile
import subprocess
with tarfile.open("6genomes.tgz", "r:gz") as tar:
    for m in tar.members():
        if m.isreg():
            f = tar.extractfile(m)
            new_filename = generate_new_filename(f.name)
            with open(new_filename, 'wb') as new_file:
                proc = subprocess.Popen(['bgzip', '-c'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=new_file)
                proc.stdin.write(f.read())
                proc.stdin.close()
                proc.wait()
            f.close()
```

Comment: If you could help me further.. it would be a treat. Based on what you posted I've come up to this:
`#!/usr/bin/env python
import tarfile, subprocess, re
mov = []
def clean(s):
   s = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z_]', '', s)
   s = re.sub('^[^a-zA-Z_]+', '', s)
   return s
with tarfile.open("LightTableLinux.tar.gz", "r:gz") as tar:
    for file in tar.getmembers():
        if file.isreg():
            proc = subprocess.Popen(tar.extractfile(file).read(), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
But I get this:
`OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long` Is there any workaround?

Comment: Popen takes a filename as first argument. The read() method gives you the contents, the bytes of the file.
What are you trying to do? I mean you try to pipe it to what?

Comment: I am trying to pipe each of the extracted files to bgzip, lets say somehow like this: 
`mov = file.name
proc = subprocess.Popen(tar.extractfile(clean(mov)), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen('bgzip -c > ' + clean(mov), stdin = proc, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
mov = None`
so that bgzip can compress them again.

Comment: extractfile give you a file-like object, so you can use it to feed bgzip (which I don't know) like this:

    f1 = tar.extractfile(file)
    f2 = open(clean(f1.name)+'bgzip', 'wb')
    subprocess.call(['bgzip', '-c'], stdin=f1, stdout=f2)

If I understand correctly your "clean" method is to generate a clean filename, is it?

Comment: Yes, "clean" does exactly that. I tried your latest suggestion but now I'm getting `AttributeError: 'ExFileObject' object has no attribute 'fileno'`. I'm sorry for all this.. I just got into python. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I edited my answer to use a pipe with subprocess as call needs a read file (with a file descriptor, a fileno) and file-like object is not enough.
I didn't test this version but it should work.

Comment: It works like a charm. I just can't thank you enough.