# OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long while using Popen - Python

Tags: python, pipe, stdout

As I started asking on a previous question, I'm extracting a tarball using the tarfile module of python. I don't want the extracted files to be written on the disk, but rather get piped directly to another program, specifically bgzip.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tarfile, subprocess, re
mov = []
def clean(s):
   s = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z_]', '', s)
   s = re.sub('^[^a-zA-Z_]+', '', s)
   return s
with tarfile.open("SomeTarballHere.tar.gz", "r:gz") as tar:
    for file in tar.getmembers():
        if file.isreg():
            mov = file.name
            proc = subprocess.Popen(tar.extractfile(file).read(), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
            proc2 = subprocess.Popen('bgzip -c > ' + clean(mov), stdin = proc, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)           
            mov = None
```

**But now I get stuck on this:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preformat.py", line 12, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen(tar.extractfile(file).read(), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long
```

Is there any workaround for this? I have been using the `LightTableLinux.tar.gz` (it contains the files for a text editor program) as a tarball to test the script on it.

Comment: `Popen(tar.extractfile(file).read())` you are passing in the *contents* of the particular file in the tarfile as the program name to execute.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is raised in the forked-off child process when trying to execute the target program from this invocation:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(tar.extractfile(file).read(), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

This

1. reads the contents of an entry in the tar file
2. tries to execute a program with the name of the contents of that entry.

Also your second invocation won't work, as you are trying to use shell redirection without using `shell=True` in `Popen()`:

```
proc2 = subprocess.Popen('bgzip -c > ' + clean(mov), stdin = proc, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

The redirect may also not be necessary, as you should be able to simply redirect the output from `bgzip` to a file from python directly.

Edit:  Unfortunately, despite `extractfile()` returning a *file-like object*, `Popen()` expects a real `file` (with a `fileno`). Hence, a little wrapping is required:

```
with tar.extractfile(file) as tarfile, file(clean(mov), 'wb') as outfile:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        ('bgzip', '-c'),
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=outfile,
    )
    shutil.copyfileobj(tarfile, proc.stdin)
    proc.stdin.close()
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30487599/1988874
You cannot use the file-like object created by extractfile as Popen wants a file object with a real fileno.

Comment: @CyrillePontvieux: Thanks for the update. That actually looks like something that should be mentioned in `subprocess`'s documentation, because for me the docs actually state otherwise. Fixed in answer.